# Implement NumericUpDown spinner control on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: user-controls, windows-phone-7, spinner

I need a control to enter small numbers on Windows Phone 7 and would like to have some kind of endless spinner control like the one for entering day and month and the date setting of the device.

Is there a standard control to spin through these kind of selections? Or at least some way how to build this kind of control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options here -

1. [Nick Randolphs' Windows Phone 7 Wheel Control](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/10/Windows-Phone-7-Wheel-Control.aspx) ([Clint Rutkas' updated version](http://www.betterthaneveryone.com/archive/2010/08/17/improving-a-controlndashwindows-phone-7-wheel-control.aspx))
2. [Rudi Grobler's LoopingSelector](http://www.rudigrobler.net/blog/2011/9/27/silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit-is-loopy.html)

I hope either of these two controls will help you in your app development. I maintain a list of [Windows Phone 7 developer resources here](http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/windows-phone-7-resources/) (including a number of WP7 controls)

Hope this helps,
indyfromoz

Comment: Thanks! Notes: Nick Randolphs looks ok, but feels very sluggish compared to the datepicker in the settings, and I'd prefer a control which can spin around to maxvalue when moved below minvalue.

Comment: But the second example looks and feels great, I'll dig deeper into that one, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you already using the Windows Phone Toolkit then you can use the same LoopingSelector control from the DatePicker. You need to implement a data source for it, but it's pretty simple.