# WP7 using LoopingSelector in a UserControl

Tags: user-controls, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

It seems that this should be straightforward. I apologize in advance if this is an amazingly stupid, but I'm just not seeing it.

I want to have a textbox tied to a user control with 2 spinners on it. Exactly how the toolkit's DatePicker works, but with custom data. I can get the LoopingSelectors setup in a usercontrol, no problem. But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to make that pop up on click of the textbox. I thought about reverse engineering the DatePicker code, but there is a lot going on in there and I don't think all that much of it applies to what I'm trying to do... I also considered the ListPicker and LongListSelector, but my data really lends itself to the LoopingSelector format.

I have scoured the web for a couple of days and found nothing of use yet. I found some similar questions like -
[Implement NumericUpDown spinner control on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022074/implement-numericupdown-spinner-control-on-windows-phone-7)

But, that doesn't really address using the LoopingSelectors in a real world scenario with a user control with show/hide ability.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into the `Popup` control?

Answer (score 0):

For a consistent user experience I'd go with the DatePicker implementation approach. I know that it involves way more work than feels sane, but I recently did exactly that for a duration picker (hours/minutes/seconds) and it just feels natural.